# How do you make a React Native ActivityIndicator appear after an onPress to show something is loading?

Tags: javascript, react-native, hook, use-effect, activity-indicator

When navigating between Screen 1 and Screen 2, the user presses a button. After pressing, it can sometimes take a few seconds to before the app navigates them to the next screen, so it does not look like anything is happening. How would I go about making an activity indicator appear until they are navigated to the next page? I have gotten an ActivityIndicator to work while other things load, but that's not until they navigate to that page.

Below is my code that launches the activity indicator while the maps page is loading:

```
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

  const renderLoading = () =>  {
        if (isLoading) {
            return (         
            <View style = {{justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: '#d3d3d3', textAlign: 'center', height: height, width: width}}>
            <ActivityIndicator
            color = 'black'
            size = 'large'
            animated = {false}
          />
          <Text style = {[ styles.text, {textAlign: 'center'}]}>{i18n.t('loading')}</Text>
          </View>

            );
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }


     <View style = {styles.container}>
        {renderLoading}
        ....
     </View>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "navigate", are you actually navigating (using, for example, `react-native-navigation`), or are you just showing a different screen (e.g. component)?

Comment: So the main question is, do you have control over the "maps" page, or is that a component/screen provided by a third party?

Comment: So sorry, I became tied up with other things. We do have control over the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the map screen I would recommend putting the spinner in that component. In other words, if **you** are doing the rendering, you will be able to determine at what stage you want to show the map instead of the spinner:

```
function IRenderTheMap(): ReactElement {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Load/preper/render map data, whatever
    // ..

    // Somehow determine that enough content has loaded
    if (isReadyToShow) setLoading(false);
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) return <Spinner />;
  // otherwise return your result
}
```

If you are using some "third-party" component that renders the map, it hopefully has some sort of callback prop that tells you if it finished loading. So check the docs and look for that.:

```
function IJustContainTheMap(): ReactElement {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  
  return (
    <View>
      {isLoading && (
        // Absolutely position the spinner so it's on top of the map
        <OverlaySpinner />
      )}
      <Map onLoadEnd={() => setIsLoading(false)} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

If the component you are using to render the map does not provide that... well I think you are out of luck. Probably best off bugging the library author to either add an "onLoadEnd" prop (or similar) or render a spinner themselves.

Or one may always for the library and add a feature themselves, but that's most of the time quite hard.

Answer (score 1):

Update your code from this

```
<View style = {styles.container}>
   {renderLoading}
   ....
</View>
```

To this

```
<View style = {styles.container}>
   {renderLoading()}
   ....
</View>
```

Comment: Huh, yeah, that's correct. But I don't think that's what they were asking... I think

Comment: I think they are asking the same, they want to show an activity indicator to user until something happens, no?

Comment: I think you caught a mistake in their code but did not answer the "text" they asked. Still, I would leave this answer as it is until they specify (I'm also not sure). :)

Comment: Sorry guys, I completely forgot to reply to these earlier. You guys were both right in your execution which is why I upvoted both of them, but Elias actually helped us with something that we didn't know we needed, so we went with his. Much appreciated from the both of you, keep up the good work! - MK

Comment: Yes the error belongs to function calling